# PWA gap between bottom navigation and screen

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, safari, progressive-web-apps

I'm wondering if anyone has had a similar experience when trying to develop a PWA for iOS.

Essentially I have a navigation bar at the bottom of my app and there is a large distance between the bottom of the navigation and the bottom of the screen where the safari url bar would typically be, i'm wondering how I should go about removing this empty space, I find that after I add the PWA to my home screen, if I close both safari and the PWA app instance then restart the PWA the app reloads without the bar but this isnt the ideal user experience for us.

As far as I know I am using the correct meta tags which should have hopefully resolved the issue:

```
<Head>
    <meta name='theme-color' content='#fff' />
    <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes'></meta>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width = device-width'></meta>
    <meta name='viewport' content='height = device-height'></meta>
    <meta
      name='viewport'
      content='initial-scale = 1.05, user-scalable = yes'
    ></meta>
    <meta
      name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style'
      content='black-translucent'
    ></meta>
    <meta name='emotion-insertion-point' content='' />
  </Head>
```

[bottom gap between nav and screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYz8A.png)